# Is there a way to extract top keys of a memcached bucket in couchabase

Tags: java, rest, memcached, key, couchbase

Via http interface of couchbase, you can see real time top keys stored in a `Memcached` bucket, along with various statistics.
However I can not find a way of extracting those top keys, or extracting the value of such a key. I gave a look on Couchbase documentation, but I didn't find anything relevant.
I used java and the rest API, but with no success.
For `Couchbase` buckets (and not `Memcached`), a simple `GET`, would be something like this:

```
server:8091/couchBase/couchbase_bucket_name/key
```

and you get the response.
If you do the same for the `Memcached` bucket, you get `not found` as response.
How to extract top keys for `Memcached` bucket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command will work on both couchbase and memcache buckets to retreive the hot keys

```
curl -u Administrator:password http://YOUR_IP:8091/pools/default/buckets/NAME_OF_BUCKET/stats
```

A lot of data will be returned but at the end of the stats you'll find hot_keys which will contain a list of your hot keys with ops a second :

```
"hot_keys":[{"name":"123","ops":0.000502008032128514}]
```

In regards to not finding keys in memcache buckets, if it is not found you either didn't set that key or you have set the time to live (ttl) shorter than the time between setting and getting the key.

Comment: Hey scalabilitysolved and xmenymenzmen, i just tried what you proposed. it works!! It's only a bit tricky 'cause you need to follow the structure server/pools/default/buckets/BUCKET_NAME/stats. thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @gandalf_the_cool - I wrote a ruby script that parses the response and provides an easier overview for the hot keys and some others stats here https://github.com/scalabilitysolved/couchbase-hot-keys

Comment: Thanks a lot scalabilitysolved.If someone wants to extract the top keys,in java, where String answer is the get request to http://YOUR_IP:8091/pools/default/buckets/NAME_OF_BUCKET/stats: 
`String keys = answer.substring(answer.indexOf("\"hot"), answer.length()).substring(11);                  List<String> topKeysList = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println(keys);
JsonMemcache[] topKeys = new Gson().fromJson(keys.substring(keys.indexOf("["), keys.indexOf("]") + 1), JsonMemcache[].class);
for (JsonMemcache json : topKeys){
topKeysList.add(json.getName());}
System.out.println(topKeysList);`

Answer (score 0):

How about this? [Couchbase Bucket Statistics](http://www.couchbase.com/docs//couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-restapi-bucket-stats.html). You should be able to get the hot keys using the command that's mentioned in this documentation. I haven't tried it myself but I believe it should work for both memcached and couchbase bucket. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

this will provide th top keys for past 24 hours

```
curl -u Administrator:password http://YOUR_IP:8091/pools/default/buckets/NAME_OF_BUCKET/stats?zoom=day | python -mjson.tool
```